unit test that code in after_this_request + call_on_close was executed after request
The example code below is similar to this answer, it runs a function after a Flask response has been returned. This works just fine.
My question is how can I unit test via the Flask.test_client that my_task() was called during the test ?
It seems that the Flask.test_client by default does not trigger after_this_request actions.
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # create response
    msg = 'Hello World!'
    @flask.after_this_request
    def add_close_action(response):
        @response.call_on_close
        def process_after_request():
            # post-response tasks
            self.my_task()
        return response
    return msg


Test client doesn't wait for the response to be fully processed as it would in a live server. You might need to simulate this behavior during testing. Maybe, you can trigger your functions manually in the testing phase.

the point is to test that the fn was executed during a Flask request. If I trigger the fn manually then the test is moot.
